# select paged nodes by using selectNode of drupal 7 service module?

Tags: services

i'm developing a mobile apps call the drupal service, i'want to get paged nodes of relative taxonomy_term, selectNodes seems can help

http://domainABC.com/my_services/taxonomy_term/selectNodes/

But how do i call page 2 of the nodes of the taxonomy_term (suppose 25 nodes per page)?

i looked the source code (taxonomy_resources.inc) but still don't have idea to do ,

```
    function taxonomy_service_select_nodes($tid = '', $pager, $limit,  $order) {
      $result = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid, (bool)$pager, $limit, $order);
      foreach ($result as $nid) {
        $node = node_load($nid);
        if ($uri = services_resource_uri(array('node', $nid))) {
          $node->uri = $uri;
        }
        $nodes[] = $node;
      }
      if (empty($nodes)) {
        return services_error(t('No nodes were found with tid @tid', array('@tid' => $tid)), 404);
      }
      return $nodes;
    }

'actions' => array(
        'selectNodes' => array(
          'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/taxonomy_resource'),
          'help'   => t('This method returns all nodes with provided taxonomy id.'),
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          'callback' => 'taxonomy_service_select_nodes',
          'args'     => array(
            array(
              'name'         => 'tid',
              'type'         => 'string',
              'description'  => t('The vocabulary ids to retrieve, separated by comma.'),
              'source'       => array('data' => 'tid'),
              'optional'     => FALSE,
            ),
            array(
              'name'         => 'pager',
              'type'         => 'int',
              'description'  => t('Whether the nodes are to be used with a pager (the case on most Drupal pages) or not (in an XML feed, for example).'),
              'source'       => array('data' => 'pager'),
              'optional'     => TRUE,
              'default value'=> TRUE,
            ),
            array(
              'name'         => 'limit',
              'type'         => 'int',
              'description'  => t('Maximum number of nodes to find.'),
              'source'       => array('data' => 'limit'),
              'optional'     => TRUE,
              'default value'=> FALSE,
            ),
            array(
              'name'         => 'order',
              'type'         => 'int',
              'description'  => t('The order clause for the query that retrieve the nodes.'),
              'source'       => array('data' => 'order'),
              'optional'     => TRUE,
              'default value'=> array('t.sticky' => 'DESC', 't.created' => 'DESC'),
            ),
          ),
```

The callback function

```
function taxonomy_service_select_nodes($tid = '', $pager, $limit,  $order) {
  $result = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid, (bool)$pager, $limit, $order);
  foreach ($result as $nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid);
    if ($uri = services_resource_uri(array('node', $nid))) {
      $node->uri = $uri;
    }
    $nodes[] = $node;
  }
  if (empty($nodes)) {
    return services_error(t('No nodes were found with tid @tid', array('@tid' => $tid)), 404);
  }
  return $nodes;
}
```

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(post)

The url link should be

http://domainABC.com/my_services/taxonomy_term/selectNodes?page=1

parameter:

tid=1

problem fixed.